# How to add animation for showing and hiding contextual action mode?

Tags: java, android

I am wondering how to animate going into and out of the contextual action mode. I am looking for an animation like in the app AwSms when you long press on a conversation (image provided, sorry for no video) The animation is essentially a ripple that comes from the middle and expands outwards on the Action Bar. I have searched long and far with no foreseeable way to animate the contextual action mode. It was definitely done here but I am not sure how. Thank you very much in advance!

Things I have tried:

```
public ActionMode.Callback iconEditCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_iconmanager_edit, menu);
        mode.getCustomView().startAnimation(ripple);
        return true;
    }
```

I also tried:

```
getSupportActionBar.setShowHideAnimationEnabled(true);
```

[image]

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Also, it's better to explain how does the animation work in text rather than showing an image

Comment: @Jeremy Ok, updated OP. So it is a ripple animation that comes from the center of the Action Bar.